# Equations, autoref and parenthesis

Tags: hyperref, equations

In a document at my workplace, `\autoref` is redefined in the following way:

```
\renewcommand{\autoref}[1]{\cref{#1}}
```

I suppose this is important because it probably means that I cannot just overwrite `\equationautorefname`.

For equations, this results in something like "Equation (5.1)". The parenthis are fine when they are shown next to the equation, but in the text we want them to be displayed without the parenthesis.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: the parentheses are there for a reason.  most authors don't write something that ends up as "equation (5.1)"; they have only the number, and if the parentheses aren't there, a reader can't tell the difference between equation 5.1 and section 5.1.  if you *do* write out `equation \ref{eq:5.1}`, as you say, you don't want the parens, but that's a subjective choice.  gonzalo's answer appears to do the job compactly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The presence of `\cref` in your question suggests the use of `cleveref`; in this case, use \crefformat to (re)format how the aspect of the cross-reference should be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

\crefformat{equation}{equation~\textup{#2#1#3}}
\Crefformat{equation}{Equation~\textup{#2#1#3}}

\renewcommand\autoref[1]{\cref{#1}}

\begin{document}

\autoref{equ:test}
\begin{equation}
\label{equ:test}
a = b.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

`\textup` makes sure the equation number will always be upright.

By the way, instead of redefining `\autoref`, it would be better perhaps to define your own new command.

Comment: It's common to ensure the equation number is upright, so  `\textup{#2#1#3}` seems better.

Comment: @egreg you're (up)right (Sorry for the bad joke). I've incorporated this into my answer. Thanks.

Comment: This seems to work, apart from capitalization at the beginning of the sentence, but that's probably because of that weird redefinition of `\autoref`. Unfortunately, I probably cannot change that, as it's a template from work.

Comment: Oh, and what do you guys mean by upright?

Comment: Fixed my capitalization issue. Works beautifully. Thank you very much, you're a wizard. :)

Comment: @Franz -- "upright" means that, even in a normally italicized theorem environment, the equation number will remain roman.