# remove parentheses that surround equation labels

Tags: equations, cleveref, parentheses

My mWE is (following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131393/61047))--

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalise,nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\creflabelformat{equation}{#2#1#3}
\begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
    \label{eq:1}
    x = y
    \end{equation}

    \cref{eq:1}
\end{document}
```

and output is --

[image]

This is fine. But I would like to present my equation without parentheses both in the environment (label) and also while referring to keep it consistent. Something like --

```
x = y                 1
```

Could some one point out the problem or give me a hint to work this out ? Additionally, (if asking this is allowed here), what is the preferred way in thesis?

**Edit**

By adding an additional line --

```
\crefrangelabelformat{equation}{#3#1#4 to #5#2#6}
```

does not make a difference.

Comment: relevant: [Removing the brackets around equation numbering](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/228448/579)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `\newtagform` command from `mathtools` to create another `equation` labelling style.

Say `\usetagform{noparen}` for example, if the tagform is named `noparen`.

The `\creflabelformat` command is only responsible for the display of the reference.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalise,nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}

\creflabelformat{equation}{#2#1#3}

\newtagform{noparen}{}{}
\usetagform{noparen}

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
    \label{eq:1}
    x = y
    \end{equation}

    \cref{eq:1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A few words of explanation and a picture would not go astray:)

Comment: @Andrew: I just posted this, alright? ;-)

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise it was a work in progress..

Comment: @Christian Hupfer, Thanks. I hope this will not affect/break the citations (using biblatex) or any others parentheses used in math env.

Comment: @Amit: I don't suspect that -- the tagform is an equation number specific command/feature